# Send "Total Vat Amount" with Invoice and Description from my database to Xero account

Tags: put, invoice, tax, xero-api

I am using "Invoice PUT method" to store invoice details from server to Xero account.
Is there any way to import "Total Vat Amount" with Invoice and Description?
Because some of my old invoice are not include Vat amount.

I have found a tag "TaxAmount". Is it same as Vat amount? If yes, then how can I use "TaxAmount" in Invoice PUT method. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, VAT is equal to tax.

In Xero API, TotalTax is a read-only value thus cannot be used with PUT. However, you can use TaxAmount to insert the tax calculation.

Notes:

1. TaxAmount is normally used to insert  your own tax calculation. If the TaxAmount is not used, Xero will automatically calculates its value from the default tax rate of the nominal/account code.
2. Xero calculates taxes for each  line item(s). Thus if your invoice only a single line item, the TaxAmount = TotalTax